# Why can't you store an object of type <ParentInterface> in a container of type <ChildInterface> in Java?

Tags: java

I've created an interface:

```
MyList<E> extends List<E>{
...
}
```

However when I try to do: `MyList<_MyClass> = new LinkedList<_MyClass>()`, I get a compiler error.

If `MyList` by definition has all of the methods in `List`, why can't I assign it?
If I try to cast it, I get a run-time cast exception.

What am I missing?

EDIT. Thanks for all the responses guys. I thought that you could use this in conjunction with the new 1.8 default methods to hack together something like C# extension methods. I.e. MyList has a bunch of default methods for working on List(and no others), but I see now why this is conceptually impossible.

Comment: You're missing that Java doesn't do "duck typing" (look that up if you need). Having the same methods has no impact on assignability in Java. For Java, the type needs to be made explicitly. For an object of a reference type A to be assignable to a variable of another reference type B, A needs to be the same as B, or it needs to extend B (directly or indirectly), or it needs to implement B (directly or indirectly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about it in terms of an easier interface.

Suppose the core library had an interface for Animal.
And an implementation called Dog.  That is, Dog implements Animal.

Now you come along and create a new implementation of Animal called Human.

Human also implements Animal.

So now I can do this.

```
Animal  a1, a2;
a1 = new Dog();
a2 = new Human();
```

But I can NOT do this.

```
Human h = new Dog();
```

Sure, both Humans and Dogs are Animals, but there is no way that a Dog can stand in for a human.  That is a compile time exception there.

Now you have a slightly more complex case.

List is your main interface, and the core implementation is LinkedList.  That is, LinkedList implements List.

So extending my analogy, you have created a new class called HumanList that also extends List.

So repeating what I did before, you can do this.

```
List<String>  b1, b2;

b1 = new LinkedList<String>;
b2 = new HumanList<String>;
```

But you can not do this.

```
HumanList<String> = new LinkedList<String>.
```

Sure, both HumanList and LinkedList are both implementations of List.   But a LinkedList can not stand in for a HumanList in all situations.

This is because your HumanList implementation might, in addition to the List interface, have other methods such as displaySocialSecurityNumbers().

If your HumanList has no other methods besides List, and you will never need it to do so, then you can do the following.

```
List<E>  b2 = new HumanList<E>();
```

Finally, as Xgord already suggested, if you want to suggest that your HumanList is a type of LinkedList, then you should have HumanList extend LinkedList.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `MyList` objects *aren't* of type `LinkedList`, which is what you're assigning.

Both `MyList` and `LinkedList` extend `List`, making both of them `List` type objects. By assigning `MyList<_MyClass> = new LinkedList<_MyClass>()`, however, you are asserting that a `LinkedList` object is a `MyList` object, which is not the case.

Change your class to:

```
MyList<E> extends LinkedList<E>{
...
}
```

and it should work.

***Edit***

Just realized I fell victim to the Is-A trap, too. If you do `MyList<E> extends LinkedList<E>`, then you would actually need to swap your assignment to: `LinkedList<_MyClass> x = new MyList<_MyClass>()`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Teto has said, it will break the [Liskov Substitutuion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming that
>   states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then
>   objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., an
>   object of the type T may be substituted with its subtype object of the
>   type S) without altering any of the desirable properties of that
>   program (correctness, task performed, etc.).

In your case, `MyList` may add some behavior which is not part `List` and hence will not be part of `LinkedList`.
And so `LinkedList` cannot be substituted for `MyList`